# How to hide parents of a specific child-class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to hide parents of an element with the class ".close" when clicking. In details: If a user clicks on an element with the class "close" I want the parent-container of the clicked element to be hidden.

So I try that one:

```
$(this).(".close").click(function() {
    $(this).parent.addClass("hide");
    location.hash = "#hidden";
});
```

where .hide is

```
.hide{
display:none;
}
```

But that doesn't work out. How else would I trigger things then?

Comment: have you tried `$(this).parent().addClass("hide");`

Comment: `parent.addClass('hide')` should be `parent().addClass('hide')`. Closing as a typo

Comment: What is this `$(this).(".close")` supposed to do ?

Comment: also what does `(this)` ref to before your click event. try `$(".close").click(function()`

Comment: `$(this).(".close").` ---> `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (`

Comment: You got to read up on the basics of JS and jQuery syntax, you can’t just invent your own and then “wonder” why that does not work.

Comment: I think this is genuine programming question and not something for VTC appetite. We being good community should correct the user as its valid programming question with some errors in it

Comment: As I ahve multiple .close-blocks in different containers I wanted to make sure that only the "real" parent gets closed. Thought the "this"-identifier would be the correct one therefore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should look like this:

```
$(".close").click(function(e) { //check selector
    $(this).parent().addClass("hide"); //parent() is a function
    location.hash = "#hidden";
});
```

Comment: @Script47 i belive that's sometimes it's better to post an answer rather then a comment to clearly show where mistakes are located.

Comment: As the one who opened the question I - of course - agree. I guess what you're doing here is :
Making the close-class the trigger of the click and then the assigned parent of the specific close-parent gets the class added. 
So, it is not necessary if I have multiple close-classes in different parents to tell which is the exact trigger?

Comment: @Daiaiai yeap it's not necessery. You get current parent with second line

Answer (score -1):

You can use jQuery function hide.

```
$('.close').click(function(element) {
    $(element.target).parent().hide()
});
```

Or by ES6 standards.

```
$('.close').click( (element) => {
    $(element.target).parent().hide()
});
```